# Update Firebase data in tableView cell on tap

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase real time database to display posts in a tableView. I want to increase the number of likes of a specific post when the user double taps the corresponding cell.

I got the double tap working and am already printing out the correct `indexPath`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  // double tap
  let doubleTapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDoubleTap(sender:)))
  doubleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
  postTableView.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapGestureRecognizer)
}
```

And here's what I tried according to the Firebase documentation to update the likes:

```
func handleDoubleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
  let touchPoint = sender.location(in: postTableView)
  if let indexPath = postTableView.indexPathForRow(at: touchPoint) {
    print(indexPath)
    let post = posts[indexPath.row]
    let oldLikes = post.likes
    let newLikes = oldLikes! + 1
    let postUpdates = ["\(post.likes)": newLikes]
    database.updateChildValues(postUpdates)
    postTableView.reloadData()
  }
}
```

It doesn't throw any errors but is not working.

This is the database structure:

[image]

And here's how I declared the database:

```
struct post {
  let author : String!
  let creationDateTime : String!
  let content : String!
  let likes : Int!
}
```

And in `viewDidLoad`

```
let database = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
```

This is how I create a post:

```
@IBAction func savePost(_ segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
    let addPostVC = segue.source as! AddPostViewController
    let author = currentUser.displayName
    let date = Date()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
    let dateResult = formatter.string(from: date)
    let creationDateTime = "\(dateResult)"
    let content = addPostVC.passTextContent
    let likes = 0
    let post : [String : AnyObject] = ["author" : author as AnyObject,
                                       "content" : content as AnyObject,
                                       "creationDateTime" : creationDateTime as AnyObject,
                                       "likes" : likes as AnyObject]
    database.child("Posts").childByAutoId().setValue(post)
}
```

And this how I retrieve the data in `viewDidLoad`

```
database.child("Posts").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: {
  snapshot in
  let postID = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["postID"] as? String ?? ""
  let author = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["author"] as? String ?? ""
  let content = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["content"] as? String ?? ""
  let creationDateTime = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["creationDateTime"] as? String ?? ""
  let likes = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["likes"] as? Int ?? 0
  self.posts.insert(post(postID: postID, author: author, creationDateTime: creationDateTime, content: content, likes: likes), at: 0)
  self.postTableView.reloadData()
})
```

Comment: Are there any updates in the firebase database for the `post.likes` after you double tap?

Comment: No, simply nothing happens

Comment: ok, can you show your database structure and can how do you declare the variable `database`? I mean, please add it to your question

Comment: Sure, did that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with your database reference. When you do `let database = FIRDatabase.database().reference()` then you are refering to the main node in your database structure. This means that you will be working with the structure under the root in your database Json. The only child of it will be the `Posts` key.

When you do

```
let postUpdates = ["\(post.likes)": newLikes]
database.updateChildValues(postUpdates)
```

you are trying to update the value under the root node, which clearly does not exist. The only reference it can find is the key `Posts`.

In order to perform the update in the correct place, you could get child references from your main reference, especially one to the post you are interested in updating.

For example, you could do the following:

```
let postReference = database.child("Here goes the post Id").
```

Then, you will be able to use `updateChildValues` correctly on this new reference, since it will be updating the specific post.

Another thing that may be used wrong is the dictionary that is being sent to the `updateChildValues`. The structure of the dictionary that you have to provide is the following:

```
["key that you want to update": new value]
```

So in your case, instead of providing the previous like count and the new like count, you should provide a dictionary as the following:

```
let postUpdates = ["likes": newLikes]
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, that makes sense, but how do I get the `postID`of the selected cell?

Comment: You're welcome! Well, I imagine you are getting the posts that you are showing in the tableView from the firebase database, aren't you? Then you should also save the `Id` from the objects returned by firebase to your `post` struct. I can't see in your code how you are creating/retrieving the posts

Comment: I added how I create and retrieve the data - now I'm struggling adding the `autoID` to the `post`

Comment: what are you having trouble with? Can't access the id?

Comment: Ok finally got it! Thanks for your help!